# Is it possible to send keys in Selenium via commad line argument in console not via hardcoding the throught sendkeys("name")?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

Hey all I have a question.
My assignment is that my program takes a command-line argument and then prints out the data.
I managed to navigate to the desired page and also print out the data I need but I did it with `.sendKeys("name i need here")`. Is it possible that at the start there would be like a question "what name do you want to type in" and you would then type the name in the command-line and everything else would play out the same?

Here's my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class Scraper {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        
        driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys("Luka Dončić");  
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[2]/div/button[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/input[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='players']/div[1]/div[1]/strong/a")).click();

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("div_per_game"));

        List<WebElement> trojke = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[data-stat='fg3a_per_g']"));
        

        List<WebElement>  sezona = element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='per_game']/tbody/tr/th/a"));

        for (WebElement s: sezona)
        {
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }

        for (WebElement t : trojke)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getText());

        }


    }
}
```

So instead of `sendKeys("Luka Dončić")` that automatically puts the name in the search box of a page I want to write the name myself in command line and when I press enter or something the rest would execute the same. Is it possible?

Here's the page I want to send the name to in the search box: https://www.basketball-reference.com/

Oh yes and I'm using Java with Selenium and Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending the text to the web element you can read the user input from console

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner my_scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String my_text = my_scan.nextLine();
```

so now you can send the `my_text`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys(my_text);
```

the entire code will look like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByXPath;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Scraper {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        
        driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/");

        Scanner my_scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String my_text = my_scan.nextLine();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys(my_text);  
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[2]/div/button[3]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/input[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='players']/div[1]/div[1]/strong/a")).click();

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("div_per_game"));

        List<WebElement> trojke = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[data-stat='fg3a_per_g']"));
        

        List<WebElement>  sezona = element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='per_game']/tbody/tr/th/a"));

        for (WebElement s: sezona)
        {
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }

        for (WebElement t : trojke)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getText());

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is "allowed" here since i'm new to stackoverflow but i have another question and i can't post it for another 90min. My output is okay but its like first there are 3 seasons and below theres the 3PA average. i want it to be like first season - 3PA avg and so on. so the season and 3PA is side by side. i tried nested For loops but seasons somehow multiply but the result is side by side cuz i can use s.getText() + t.getText() and i can't use this if i'm not in a nested loop. is there a workaround or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, I never asked multiple questions one after another so I don't know. But if there is a such limitation - I can't help with it. The only thing I can help - when you post another question just tag me so if I will be online I will see it and will be happy to help again :)

Comment: i just posted the question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67509526/print-out-seasons-and-three-pointers-side-by-side-not-one-below-the-other-in-jav