# Print out seasons and three pointers side by side not one below the other in Java with Selenium. How can i do that?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Okay, last question for today since this is the last step in my project.

I managed to navigate through pages to get to the desired page. Then I need to print out Seasons and 3PA from a table. I'm using Java with Selenium and Maven. I tried nested `for` loops and it does print out the result correctly side by side (only because I can System.out.printIn(s.getText() + "  " + t.getText()) but the season multiply by 3.. I now have two separate `for` loops and it works but the result is like this:

```
2018-19
2019-20
2020-21
7.1
8.9
8.2
```

and i want it to be like this:

```
2018-19   7.1
2019-20   8.9
2020-21   8.2
```

Here's my code:

```
public class Scraper {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe");
     
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
        
        driver.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/");

        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='qc-cmp2-ui']/div[2]/div/button[3]")).click();

        Scanner my_scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Vpisi ime igralca: ");

        String my_text = my_scan.nextLine();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("// [@id='header']/div[3]/form/div/div/input[2]")).sendKeys(my_text);  

        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[3]/form/input[1]")).click();
        driver.findElement(ByXPath.xpath("//*[@id='players']/div[1]/div[1]/strong/a")).click();

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("div_per_game"));

        List<WebElement> threePointers = element.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[data-stat='fg3a_per_g']"));
        

        List<WebElement>  Seasons = element.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='per_game']/tbody/tr/th/a"));

        for (WebElement s: Seasons)
        {
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }

        for (WebElement t : threePointers)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getText());

        }


    }
}
```

And this is the page and the table I'm getting the data from (the Per Game table): https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/d/doncilu01.html

Hope you gurus out there can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
for (WebElement s: Seasons)
        {
            System.out.println(s.getText());
        }

        for (WebElement t : threePointers)
        {
            System.out.println(t.getText());

        }
```

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< Seasons.size(); i++){
   System.out.println(Seasons.get(i).getText() + "\t" + threePointers.get(i).getText()); 
}
```

The `\t` is to add tab between the texts from the first ans the second elements lists.
Take in account that this will work without additional logics only in case `Seasons` and `threePointers` lists are of the same length!